# Avoiding overfitting in unsupervised ML

Tags: overfitting, unsupervised-learning, pattern-recognition

I am using a unsupervised pattern matching approach to create a trade strategy. I use the output of the pattern matched results to decide whether to enter a trade or not. For deciding the best pattern parameters I run several combinations over the entire data set and choose the best parameters that yield the best profits. My question is whether this would be considered overfitting. If so, how may I avoid the same? I looked at several posts on StackOverflow but did not find anything that relates to my particular use case.